# assembly reference for folder in a project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a c# project X that contains a folder COMMON, and I have several classes in the COMMON folder.

Now in project Y; I am referencing

```
using X.Common;
```

Everything is good till now, intellisense works great.
However, when I build project Y I get "The type or namespace name 'common' doesn't exists in the namespace X(are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: Sounds like a reference is missing or you're incorrectly referencing a namespace. Could you provide a little bit more of your code?

Comment: Try right clicking on your Solution and click `Clean Solution`, then `Rebuild` it. You may also need to add a reference to your assembly explicity. (Right click on `References`...`Add Reference...`)

Comment: Thanks guys, I just needed to change my target framework. It was set to client profile some how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio, in project Y. Right click references, add reference, projects, select Project X. Try again.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to change my target framework. It was set to client profile some how.